# missing execinfo .h in arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi

Tags: crosstool-ng

ng users,

Does any body knows how to have execinfo.h header file while cross compiling arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi toolchain?

Basically I have cross compiled arm-unknown-linux-uclibcgnueabi toolchain but it doesn't have execinfo.h header. I needed execinfo.h to compile my source code.

Any suggestion please. Thanks..

Comment: Do you use `uclibc-ng` by any chance?